# How to reduce size of DatePicker in Window Universal App in Windows 10?

Tags: datepicker, visual-studio-2015, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I am working on ECommerce Universal app in Windows 10. I have DatePicker control to manage filter for Between Dates.

It is working fine in Desktop State(View) (>720). But width of DatePicker doesn't reduce in Tablet State(View) (<720).

I have set Setter for it:

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="PageSizeStatesGroup"
                          CurrentStateChanged="OnCurrentStateChanged">
            <VisualState x:Name="MediumState">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="720"  />
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <!--Set width to 215 but it doesn't reduce-->
                    <Setter Target="datepicker1.Width" Value="215"></Setter>
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
</Grid>
```

Generally, this works for other control in my application whether it is for Desktop view or Tablet view or Mobile view. But it doesn't work for DatePicker.

Can anybody suggest me how to achieve this?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DatePicker has also set MinWidth property as default, so you have to join the setter for this property too. Otherwise it takes MinWidth value, when your Width value is smaller.
It should be something like this:

```
<Setter Target="datePicker1.MinWidth" Value="215" />
```